# Export Java Project with external libraries using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

i'm trying to export my Java Project into a runnable JAR file with eclipse but if i want to run the finished JAR file I always get the error

```
Java Virtual Machine Launcher

Could not find the main class: src.main. Program will exit.
```

`src.main` is my main class, if i open the jar with winrar this class is in the folder src in the jar file.

I export the Project like this:

- Right click on the Project name
- Export
- Runnable JAR file -> Next
- Launchconfig: my main class.
- destination: ...\Desktop\asdf.jar
- Library handling: Extract required libraries into generated JAR (I also tried all the others)
- Finish
- I get a Warning: "JAR export finished with warnings. .."
- OK

The libraries are added like this:

- Right click on the Project name
- Properties
- Java Build Path
- Libraries
- Add External JARs
- And than all the libraries are together in one external folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your class name main? If so, main is reserved word in java, change name to something else which is not reserved word and try.

Comment: I changed the name, but still get the error.

Comment: Check meta-inf has entry with this class name or not?

Comment: In the meta-inf folder in the manifest datei is: `Class-Path: .`
`Main-Class: src.Start`

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshots of the project hierarchy in Eclipse and the folder view you do in WinRar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does src.Start have a proper "public static void main(String[] args)" method?

Are you trying to start the app like this:

"java -jar myjar.jar" or "java -cp myjar.jar src.start"

Also, are you building the manifest by hand, or letting eclipse do it? I don't remember ever seeing eclipse add a classpath entry in the manifest but I might have missed it.

On the "Jar Manifest Specification" panel during the export, just select "generate the manifest file" and fill in the "Main class:" entry in the input field.

Comment: I let eclipse doing it, and if i start it like this:`java -jar myjar.jar`it works, i just had to put the src folder to the jar. But why isnt it working when i just open it?

Comment: ahh! you can't run a Jar by clicking like EXE. If you want to run a jar, you need to run it from command line only (AFAIK) using Java -jar command.

Comment: I created a bat file, which contains java -jar myjar.jar, for me its working but i gave the file to a friend but he got error:`Could not find the main class: main.Start. Program will exit.`

Comment: The reason that the export function of eclipse wasn't working was: that I'm using the Java Version 1.7 and everybody else used 1.6, i changed the compile version in the settings of eclipse and everything is now working fine. But i'm now using this: `java -jar myjar.jar` to create a bat and convert this to a exe, so the programm look more familiarly for windows users. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I recommend you: don't use src.main in the way that you are doing it right now. In Java usually we use a folder called src or src/main or src/main/java to put the sources. Then, to use this as a package and class name is not a good idea. Secondly; don't call your class **main** it is not a keyword in Java, you can create a class with this name but... it's not a good idea.

And the solution to your problem: you need to set up your Main-Class and your Class-Path in your manifest file and be sure about the structure of your package (your jar), take a look into this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html), it will help you.

Comment: I know, but if you see that info in the manifest auto generate for eclipse you can see what is the class that the jar execute, what is the package, if the libraries are in the classpath... and looking within the jar you can find your classes, libraries and see if they are in the correct place.